# Angularjs steps directive doesnt work with ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs

Trying to convert jquery steps to angularjs step directive, while html child of the step directive contain ng-repeat and ng-options didn't get render.

I have to put a $timeout services component for the step directive to works (as commented out in the code below).

```
var steps = ""
// $timeout(function(){
steps = angular.element(element).children('.steps-wrapper').steps({

    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex){
        if (currentIndex == 0) {
            return true
        }else if (currentIndex == 1) {
            return true
        }else if (currentIndex == 2) {
            return true
        }
    }
})
// })

$compile(steps)(scope)
```

#### html site **/

```
<div step class="">
    <div id="checkout" class="cui-wizard steps-wrapper">
    <h3>
        <i class="icmn-cart5 wizard--steps--icon"></i>
        <span class="wizard--steps--title">Cart</span>
    </h3>
    <section>
        ...
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="(x, y) in vm.cart.getCart().items">
                    <td class="text-center">{{x+1}}</td>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        ...
    </section>
</div>
```

Plunkr link for testing.
[plunkr](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/GKKUnIebUjqhP6Qo)

Please check step 3, the loop didn't render inside steps directive. But run outside of step directive.

Comment: not sure that `element.children(pattern)` works, it is a jqLite version inside of angularjs, not a full jquery. Check that children return at least 1 item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compile: function(tElm, tAttrs, transclude) {
    tElm.wrapInner('<div class="wizard"></div>')
    tElm.children('.wizard').steps(_stepsConfig_1)

    return {
      pre: (scope, elm, attrs) =>{},
      post: (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl)=>{
        elm.children('.wizard').on('stepsOrientation', ctrl.stepsOptions.stepsOrientation)

        elm.children('.wizard').on('stepChanging', ctrl.stepsOptions.stepChanging)

        elm.children('.wizard').on('stepChanged', ctrl.stepsOptions.stepChanged)

        elm.children('.wizard').on('cancel', ctrl.stepsOptions.stepCanceled)

        elm.children('.wizard').on('finishing', ctrl.stepsOptions.stepFinishing)

        elm.children('.wizard').on('finished', ctrl.stepsOptions.stepFinished)
      }
    }
  },
...
```

initialize the jquery step first before compile of Angularjs

[working solution](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/GKKUnIebUjqhP6Qo)